# Residual calculation using CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust, cub

I have two vectors (`oldvector` and `newvector`). I need to calculate the value of the residual which is defined by the following pseudocode:

```
residual = 0;
forall i : residual += (oldvector[i] - newvector[i])^2
```

Currently, I am calculating this with two CUDA Thrust operations which are essentially doing:

```
forall i : oldvector[i] = oldvector[i] - newvector[i]
```

followed by a `thrust::transform_reduce` with a square as unary operator, which is doing:

```
residual = 0;
forall i : residual += oldvector[i]^2;
```

The problem with this is obviously the intermediate store to global memory before `transform_reduce`. Is there a more efficient approach to this problem which would fuse these two steps? Apart from writing my own CUDA kernel, is there any other option?

One approach I thought of was to write a `thrust::reduce` with zip iterators. The problem with this is that the return type of the operator has to be the same type as its input. What this means, according to me, is that the reduction operator would be returning a tuple which would mean an extra addition.

If I do write a reduction CUDA kernel, has there been any improvements made over the CUDA 1.1 example for the reduction kernel?

Comment: [thrust::inner_product](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformed__reductions.html#gad9df36f7648745ca572037727b66b48d) will do what you want.  Provide a `binary_op2` which computes the difference-squared.  Your `binary_op1` can just be `thrust::plus`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[thrust::inner_product](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformed__reductions.html#gad9df36f7648745ca572037727b66b48d) will do it in a single function call.   Your original idea can be made to work also (zipping together the two vectors and using `thrust::transform_reduce`) This code demonstrates both methods:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/inner_product.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

#define N 2

struct zdiffsq{
template <typename Tuple>
  __host__ __device__ float operator()(Tuple a)
  {
    float result = thrust::get<0>(a) - thrust::get<1>(a);
    return result*result;
  }
};

struct diffsq{
  __host__ __device__ float operator()(float a, float b)
  {
    return (b-a)*(b-a);
  }
};

int main(){

  thrust::device_vector<float> oldvector(N);
  thrust::device_vector<float> newvector(N);
  oldvector[0] = 1.0f;  oldvector[1] = 2.0f;
  newvector[0] = 2.0f;  newvector[1] = 5.0f;

  float result = thrust::inner_product(oldvector.begin(), oldvector.end(), newvector.begin(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>(), diffsq());
  std::cout << "Result: " << result << std::endl;

  float result2 = thrust::transform_reduce(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(oldvector.begin(), newvector.begin())), thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(oldvector.end(), newvector.end())), zdiffsq(), 0.0f, thrust::plus<float>());
  std::cout << "Result2: " << result2 << std::endl;
}
```

You can also investigate eliminating the functor definition used with the inner product example, by using thrust [placeholders](http://thrust.github.io/doc/namespaceplaceholders.html).

Even if you want to write your own CUDA code, the standard recommendation now for oft-used algorithms like parallel reductions and sorting, is to use [cub](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/).

And yes, the [CUDA parallel reduction sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction) and [accompanying presentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf) is still a good basic intro to a fast parallel reduction.

Answer (score 1):

Robert Crovella has already answered this question and has also suggested using [CUB](http://nvlabs.github.io/cub/).

At variance with Thrust, CUB leaves performance-critical parameters, such as the choice of specific reduction algorithm to be used and the degree of concurrency unbound, selectable by the user. These parameters can be tuned in order maximimize performance for a particular architecture and application. The parameters can be specified at compile time, so avoiding runtime performance penalties.

Below, there is a full worked example on how using CUB for residual calculation.

```
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
#include <cuda.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

#include <iostream>

#define BLOCKSIZE           256
#define ITEMS_PER_THREAD    8

const int N = 4096;

/******************************/
/* TRANSFORM REDUCTION KERNEL */
/******************************/
__global__ void TransformSumKernel(const float * __restrict__ indata1, const float * __restrict__ indata2, float * __restrict__ outdata) {

    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * gridDim.x;

    // --- Specialize BlockReduce for type float. 
    typedef cub::BlockReduce<float, BLOCKSIZE * ITEMS_PER_THREAD> BlockReduceT;

    __shared__ typename BlockReduceT::TempStorage  temp_storage;

    float result;
    if(tid < N) result = BlockReduceT(temp_storage).Sum((indata1[tid] - indata2[tid]) * (indata1[tid] - indata2[tid]));

    if(threadIdx.x == 0) atomicAdd(outdata, result);

    return;
}

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main() {

    // --- Allocate host side space for 
    float *h_data1      = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    float *h_data2      = (float *)malloc(N * sizeof(float));
    float *h_result     = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float));

    float *d_data1;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data1, N * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_data2;     gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_data2, N * sizeof(float)));
    float *d_result;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_result, sizeof(float)));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        h_data1[i] = 1.f;
        h_data2[i] = 3.f;
    }

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data1, h_data1, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_data2, h_data2, N * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    TransformSumKernel<<<iDivUp(N, BLOCKSIZE), BLOCKSIZE>>>(d_data1, d_data2, d_result);
    gpuErrchk(cudaPeekAtLastError());
    gpuErrchk(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_result, d_result, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    std::cout << "output: ";
    std::cout << h_result[0];
    std::cout << std::endl;

    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_data1));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_data2));
    gpuErrchk(cudaFree(d_result));

    return 0;
}
```